# PayPal Cart Shipping option not working

Tags: html, paypal

```
<form style="float:right" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >

                          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                          <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="shivram@gmail.com">          
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Paper">
                          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="20">                              
                          <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="3.99">
                          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                          <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                          <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                          <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">

                          <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">

                          <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
                          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
</form>
```

The shipping value is set to 3.99 .It does not add up to the invoice.

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34ZfY/ click on the buy now button(the shipping rate does not show up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because it has to be this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="3.99">
```

So if you have more products then ..

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="4.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_3" value="7.99">
```

And so on..

Comment: What if I want to show a single shipping charge for all of the products purchased ? Like a flat shipping charge of $2 ?